# Error: resolve-url-loader: error processing CSS

Tags: reactjs

I am using scss with reactJS@18.1.0
during making build for production then I am getting this error.

```
Error: resolve-url-loader: error processing CSS
  Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":1,"column":176},"source":"file://D:\\SSC-BUZZ JAN-2022\\ssc-buzz-client\\src\\styles\\index.scss","original":{"column":null},"name":null}
```

Answer (score 3):

This was driving me completely insane. What worked for me is adding

```
"resolutions": {
    "resolve-url-loader": "5.0.0"
  }
```

to `package.json` to force every package to use version 5. I can now build successfully.

Comment: `"resolutions"` works for yarn; for npm you need to use `"overrides"`.
This solution works perfectly though! :)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Using create react app with scss and npm

Comment: didn't work also for me, CRA + sass

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes ("") in your @import lines

Comment: It didn't work in my case.